# Primefaces filter minimum length

Tags: primefaces, filter

There is PrimeFaces datatable with multiple columns that can be filtered and sorted. Database contains few million rows, there is index for text search but for strings of less than 3 characters this still takes longer than I would like it to. So I would like to disable filtering for input of less than 3 characters.
My xml file looks like this:

```
<p:column headerText=... sortBy=... filterBy=... filterMatchMode="contains">
</p:column>
```

Is there a column property that would enable me to disable filter for queries that are less than 3 characters long?

Comment: Have you tried setting your filterable source record field to 3 characters, using, say, substring()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own `filterFunction=""` which does nothing if the `String` is shorter than 3 characters.

JSF page:

```
<p:column filterFunction="#{myclass.myfiltermethod}"></p:column>
```

ManagedBean:

```
public boolean myfiltermethod(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {
    String filterText = (filter == null) ? null : filter.toString().trim();
    if (filterText != null || filterText.length() < 3) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

You can see an implemented example in [Primefaces Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml), in particular the column for Price.

Answer (score 0):

filterMaxLength by using this the error will fixed.

```
> <p:column headerText=... sortBy=... filterBy=... filterMatchMode="contains" filterMaxLength ="3"> </p:column>
```

Comment: and which version of PF is this supported in ? 3.0, 3.5, 5, 8? Link to documentation?